# How can I disable rspec's progress formatter when using other formatters?

Tags: rspec

We're running rspec from Ant, so the progress formatter wasn't really an option as it wasn't giving live results.

So we're running rspec like this:

```
CI_REPORTS=$REPORTDIR/rspec

rspec src/test/rspec                             \
  --require ci/reporter/rake/rspec_loader        \
  --format documentation                         \
  --format CI::Reporter::RSpec                   \
  --format html --out $REPORTDIR/specs.html
```

This gives live-updating but rather messy output:

```
.  #equals
    is equal to itself
.    is equal to the same item obtained separately
.    is not equal to a different item
.    is not equal to something that is not an item
.    is not equal to null
```

The dot looks like it's the default `--format progress` stuff because pending results show a * there. I'm probably missing something, but I can't find a way to turn this off. The command-line documentation I get when I use `--help` doesn't describe how I can turn a formatter *off*, only how I can turn more formatters *on*...

There has to be a trick though, so what is it?

Comment: I don't see this problem in RSpec 3.4 with the built-in documentation and html formatters.

Comment: It looks like we're on 3.3. Maybe they fixed it... I'd have to read the changelog.